# External function to user displayed image

Tags: labview

So I have an external C function that returns a pointer to an array. I'm trying to figure out how to convert the pointer to something that can be be displayed on the screen using the latest version of LabView (2019, assume I have all the toolkits).

The C function signature imports fine and is designed to display 16 bit images.

```
STATUS DemoImage(unsigned short** ptr, int64* rows, int64* columns, int64 image_idx)
```

with `ptr` eventually filling a pointer containing the memory location to 16 bit image. `rows`, `columns` work as expected.

Whats the name of the controllers that convert the data type to something that can be displayed? I'd also appreciate answers that only address how to display a 8 bit images as I can convert them in my own library if worst, comes to worst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a vi.lib VI not on the palette that you can use: `GetValueByPointer`.

## Detailed walkthrough

For the step-by-step explanation, see [this NI document](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Developer-Center-Resources/Dereferencing-Pointers-from-C-C-DLLs-in-LabVIEW/ta-p/3522795?profile.language=en).

> 2D arrays are represented as an array of arrays. Since an array is really a pointer, a 2D array is a pointer to an array of pointers, where each pointer points to the individual rows of the array. So in order to dereference a 2D Array, you must first dereference the individual pointers to each row, and then dereference in individual elements in each row. The following snippet shows an example of this:
>
> [image: block diagram of iterating over a 2D array]

## Download examples

For a download with examples, see [this one instead](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Developer-Center-Resources/Calling-C-C-DLLs-Containing-Simple-and-Complex-Datatypes-from/ta-p/3522649?profile.language=en), section 4.d.

> **Returning values by reference (pass by ref)**
>
> - Function:
>   `void ReturningValuesByReference_2DArrayOfIntegers (int rows, int cols, int ***newArray);`
> - VI:
>   Returning Values By Reference 2D Array Of Integers Complete.vi

Comment: I see. If you will forgive me for asking a related question, does this kind of VI have abysmally poor runtime when the number of pixels is millions?  It would seem that function call overhead would be very high unless labview did some optimization. I'm thinking an alternative strategy, is to write a C or C++ code that performs these copy steps into a labview array. Would you estimate the difference in run-time between these two strategies to be 5x or 50x?

Comment: If you have control over the C/C++ code, I would change the signature so the 2D array is contiguous in memory (eg, pointer to first entry, size_t row_length, size_t column_count) and just [give the whole block to LabVIEW](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/LabVIEW-MoveBlock-and-getting-a-string-from-a-DLL-allocated-by/td-p/3311596?profile.language=en).

Comment: I see. So I'm wondering if there is a way to address the deep copy. In my case, the memory is already allocated by the dll. Can labview wrap this? While this example, isn't too resource intensive, I suspect this may improve the performance of some of the real-time process I'm hoping to do.

Comment: From here, your C/C++ library can use the [LabVIEW memory manager](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvexcodeconcepts/memory_manager/) to allocate memory from LabVIEW.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I go a proof of principle LabView SDK built in a few days :-)